# PrimeFaces Event:dragdrop is not supported

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces 5.3. I have a `TreeTable` and want to use drag and drop:

```
<p:treeTable id="tree" value="#{equipmentsView.root}" var="node" selectionMode="single" selection="#{equipmentsView.selectedNode}" draggable="true" droppable="true" >
    <p:ajax event="dragdrop" listener="#{equipmentsView.onDragDrop}" update="@form" />
```

Now it complains:
`javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /equipments.xhtml @47,88 <p:ajax> Event:dragdrop is not supported.`

I have `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` in my xmlns

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that no ajax behavior callback is provided for this tag.

With each tag, Primefaces defined specific events for each one.

You can see that no "dragdrop" event is defined in TreeTable in [Primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf)

TreeTable provides various ajax behavior events to respond user actions:

1. expand
2. collapse
3. select
4. unselect
5. colResize

Best regards,